# Delete one of the Consecutively HTML Element from Children of an HTML Element

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML div that I know its id and there are some children (and also their children) of it as well. What I want to do is if I see two `<br/>` elements consecutively I want to delete one of them. i.e. I mean:

```
<div id="a">
  <div>
   <span>
     <br/>
   <span>
   <span>
    <br/>
    <br/>
   <span>
  <div>
</div>
```

to be:

```
<div id="a">
  <div>
   <span>
     <br/>
   <span>
   <span>
    <br/>
   <span>
  <div>
</div>
```

Comment: will that be `<br/>` elements only or any html elements can be duplicate and you want to delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#a').find('br+br').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```js
$('br + br').remove()
```

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">
  <div>
    <span>
      <br/>
      <span>
        <span>
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <span>
            <div>
            </div>
          </span>
        </span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @kamaci that is the duty of jQuery so we could leave it to jQuery!!! it should work